# Are rich-client apps inherently more secure than webapps?

Tags: web-application, appsec, vulnerability

If I'm not mistaken, in webapps there are a lot of potential attack vectors, such as http header spoofing and what not, which are not there in typical rich-client desktop applications, such as WPF applications. To add a bit more motivation to my question, I have the feeling that most security related issues I come across in news and blog articles concern webapps. Me being a desktop developer with 0 experience in web-development, I began to wonder: are rich-client apps inherently more secure than webapps?

For example, can a simple desktop app with a classic login (username + password), a database (that resides on a remote server) that only contains usernames with hashed passwords (and salt), without any other "authentication" process, be considered less vulnerable overall (lets say towards the most common types of attacks) than a webapp that does the same?

Perhaps to make my question more focussed, based on the comments I received: What are some of the main security concerns for each type? Are there any potential vulnerabilities that exist in one but definitely aren't worrysome to the other?

Please note that I am not considering scenarios where one uses technologies of the other. For example, the desktop app should do what it does without any usage of web technologies or protocols (such as HTTP).

Comment: Each application type has their own types of potential vulnerabilities.

Comment: Ok, one of the crucial concepts to keep in mind *whenever* you say the word "secure" is the question "secure from what?". Is a rock more secure than a cat? Well, it depends on what you are talking about, the context, and what threats you are worried about.

Comment: For instance: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/84486/java-desktop-app-vs-web-service

Comment: Good point! I am having a hard time describing what "secure" means myself. Essentially, I am thinking about protection against "imitating" a legitimate user by modifying http traffic, SQL injection etc., basically anything that makes webapps vulnerable

Comment: You can also have SQLi in desktop apps, too, if you use SQL. It's not that one is inherently more vulnerable than another, but rather that one might be easier to introduce certain types of vulnerabilities in one than another. A web app and a desktop app also have radically different threats to worry about. If you hand a SQL database to be installed on the desktop, you can forget about that database being secure. You don't even need SQLi. You've handed the db to the user. Desktop apps can also be exploited to get root access on the desktop.

Comment: So, this question will be difficult to answer except to say that you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: "A web app and a desktop app also have radically different threats to worry about. If you hand a SQL database to be installed on the desktop." I guess I am looking for an eloboration and overall conclusion on that, since I myself do not have much knowledge of security engineering.

Comment: In my opinion the question is too unfocused. In real life one does not randomly pick a desktop app or web app. Instead one starts with a task which needs to be done and then chooses from apps which help in doing the task. So you might for example compare web based mail clients against desktop mail clients - but also only within the narrow task you want to do.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Well as I tried to explain, I am trying to compare a webapp and desktop app that do the *same* thing, be it a mail client or whatever. Imo which one you are actually gonna pick irl is a separate question that depends on other things apart from security, right? I am only interested in security right now, all other things equal(lly unimportant). Basically I am interested in what are the main security threats one has to worry about for each and how do they differ in that regard.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks for your comment though. I edited my question to make it more focussed.

Comment: @csstudent1418: You are still putting all possible desktop apps into one bag and all web apps into the other and ask to compare these bags. These bags are big and the variety of apps inside is large - this makes the question still too unfocused even if you are "only" asking to list the major security concerns for each bag.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich The thing is, I do not *want* to compare too specific types of applications. I want to know about anything security related that holds *in general* - hence the "inherent" in the title. From your comments should I take it as an answer that there are no inherent differences between the two types when it comes to security, i.e. every vulnerability that (potentially) exists in one also exists in the other?

Comment: @csstudent1418: If you want to have a useful general comparison you need to compare different things. The main point is not if desktop or web based but if potentially untrusted input need to be handled. While this is true for all web apps it can also be true for desktop apps, like a desktop mail client handling external mail. Also, many desktop apps use inside web technologies (like ability to display HTML) so it is unclear where exactly the line is between these two types.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I will take that into account in my question. I am imagining a strict line between the two, i.e. the desktop app should do what it does without using any web technologies or protocols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably impossible to fully quantify the different threats to each program type. My initial reaction, though, is "No". It's often easier to attack web apps - they're more often exposed and easy to find - but that doesn't mean much to a motivated attacker and most of the most-famous worms and other highly-damaging malware targeted desktop apps or other non-web software.

The following lists are not comprehensive; I just wanted to illustrate some of the many, many factors.

Some security advantages of desktop apps:

- Do not necessarily to accept traffic from the Internet directly, although some do. Those that don't usually require some victim actions (like opening a file).
- More likely to act as a client (making requests and getting responses) than a site (which is hosted by a server). Assuming the app's server is not malicious, this makes it harder for an attacker to attack the connection.
- Unless using a webview, immune to client-side web vulnerabilities such as XSS or CSRF. Even if using a webview, usually the risk is reduced because you don't browse arbitrary sites with the webview.
- Many systems support various hardening options (NX/DEP, ASLR, etc.) that make successful exploitation of some attacks hard.
- Many systems support customizable sandboxing (including containers, etc.) to allow running the code with the least privileges it needs (unfortunately, this requires developer or possibly user action that is rarely taken).

Some security disadvantages of desktop apps:

- Most do not run sandboxed (though sandboxes are becoming more common); compromising one can take over the entire computer and possibly local network, or at least everything on it that the user has access to (think ransomware, etc.).
- Much more likely to be written in native code or call into native libraries with attacker-controlled data, which means more risk of memory corruption vulnerabilities (buffer overflow, use-after-free, etc.).
- Plenty of room for confusion around the multi-user machine model (what directories or other objects are safe to use, what permissions should be set on privileged components, etc.).

Some security advantages of web apps:

- Browsers automatically provide a lot of security features that are not necessarily present elsewhere, like the same-origin policy and sandboxed system access.
- Web apps are easy to update when an issue is found, and then everybody immediately gets the patched version.
- While a compromised web app might compromise a large number of users, the damage to each user is likely less because each web app is isolated from others so most of your computer use is unaffected (note: this is less true if you share passwords across sites!).
- Browsers include support for secure communications (HTTPS) and data parsing (HTML Form formats including MIME, JSON) making it less likely people try to implement their own protocols / parsers and risk messing it up.
- Since the server is generally doing only a well-defined list of tasks and does them autonomously, it's relatively easy to restrict access to it (except on TCP 80/443) and sandbox it to limit both its attack surface and blast radius.

Some security disadvantages of web apps:

- Common, well-known and easily-weaponized attack patterns (XSS, CSRF, etc.) that are often easy to find by anybody with a browser (so, everybody).
- Browser differences in security-relevant behaviors and feature support means mitigations might cover some users but not others (less of a problem now than before, but some people still use IE, even version 10 or older).
- Confusing standards (e.g. CORS) and common misconfigurations (bad TLS suites, SAML/OAuth handling, XML entity handling) mean there's a lot you might have to know to set up a web app securely (many potential threats).
- High-value targets (compromise one app or service, potentially hit a ton of users and/or get lots of valuable data).